# Finding all paths in graph using neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a DAG and I want to find all paths in it using neo4j. For doing this I am using the following query:

```
MATCH (n)-[:REL]->(leaf)
RETURN n,leaf ;
```

However this query only return to me edges. However I want my output to be of the form:

```
  a->b->c->d->e->f->g->h->i
  a->b1->c1->d1->e1->f1->g1->h1->i1
```

Is there someway that I can use to get this output?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to look at [variable-length pattern matching](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-varlength). You'll want to add restrictions so that your start node is a root and your end node is a leaf, otherwise you'll get every subpath in the graph.

Also, you really should be using labels. For the sake of example, I'll just :Node in my Cypher snippet:

```
MATCH path = (root:Node)-[:REL*]->(leaf)
WHERE NOT ()-[:REL]->(root) AND NOT (leaf)-[:REL]->()
RETURN path
```